# Young adult fiction about a group of kids training to be astronauts

Tags: story-identification, space, ghost

I remember reading a book back in primary school, 5 or 6 years ago, about a group of kids who were part of a program to become astronauts. I vaguely remember that they were the second program, the first one ended in disaster with a blown up rocket. I remember that a ghost of one of the kids in the disaster was haunting the place and the protagonist who was a boy was trying to find out if he actually died. Can't remember much more than that, would be great if someone knew the book, I'd like to read it again! Thanks in advance for any help.

*Edit - the protagonist got very lucky was selected out of many kids, another character was a girl and I think he liked her and also there was an antagonist boy who was always a dick to the main character.

*Edit 2 - It's definitely based on Earth and im sure it wasn't specified where they were going in space, just that they were going. and the book is not as well known as Enders game: so no movie I'm pretty sure. The book was standalone too. Most of the story was the protagonists interaction with others and doing tests.

I remember one of the tests was a gforce test and they spun around a lot and the kid thought he would vomit but he didn't, then someone else did vomit and someone else had to go into the now vomit filled machine and everyone laughed. - just a small scene but it may help.

I'm pretty sure the protagonist thought he was seeing a ghost of this boy from the fail rocket, but in the end it was the boy himself, and he was trying to make sure it didn't happen again or something like that. Also the story isn't futuristic like Enders game and it has no aliens. It is pretty modern time with spaceships we have today (rockets).

Comment: I read it around 5 a the latest 6 years ago. Another small piece of information I remember is that the protagonist was selected out of a lot of kids and got very lucky. There was also a girl who i think he liked and a sort of antagonist boy who was always mean to him.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that information?

Comment: on a side note: movies get made out of unknown books all the time; probably more often than famous books...

Comment: Is it Breaking Sky by Cory McCarthy?

Comment: That's just one of many of those kinds of stories that I've read, so it might not be...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a LOT like Ender's Game. Is it possibly that?

Comment: Were there ghosts in *Ender’s Game*? Also, could you add some details about this story to help the poster know whether it’s the right one?

Comment: I can't remember if there are ghosts, but everything else matches up. Ender's game is about this guy who's chosen to go into space to command an army against aliens which are harmless and stuff.

Comment: There are no ghost in "Ender's Game", but there is however this strange psychological assessment computer that Ender "plays" with. The many scenarii he has to pass put him in strange and bizarre situations.

Comment: Nah it's not Enders game. I added some more info to the main chunk